# Имеет ли значение диагональ экрана ноутбука для верстки?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Хочу взять ноутбук, знакомый подобрал модель с неплохими комплектующими, но есть один нюанс- экран у него 15.6", 1920x1080. Насколько сильно это важно для верстки? Где-то читала, что верстать на диагонали менее 17 это очень неудобно) Что скажете?

Comment: Это в определённой степени индивидуально. У всех свои предпочтения, свои привычки. Большое значение может играть острота зрения, у кого оно хорошее - масштабирование будет более компактным и площадь экрана будет вмещать больше информации. По-хорошему, такие вещи лучше тестировать заранее.

Comment: я думаю что ноутбук с диагональю свыше 15.6" не очень удобная штука, и к тому же врядли легкая. Мне кажется что большее значение имеет количество мониторов, нежели их размер. В целом не думаю что вам будет недостаточно диагонали 15.6 (мне например хватает более чем), в будущем лучше докупить второй монитор и будет идеально. Но это все индивидуально.

Comment: Чем больше экран, тем лучше, это очевидно. Так что, если вам не важна мобильность, рассмотрите вариант покупки стационарного компьютера. Как правило, это выходит дешевле при сравнении с аналогичным ноутбуком, его проще обслуживать, периферия и комплектующие легко заменяются.

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы) Я первое время и верстала на стационарном компьютере (поэтому проблем со 2ым монитором нет), затем начала замечать,что к вечеру болит спина если долго сидеть над кодом) Именно это и заставило задуматься о покупке ноутбука

Comment: @Ksenia Если болит спина от долгого сидения за компьютером, надо покупать кресло, а не ноутбук!

Comment: Математически это просто. Попробую объяснить. Понятно что верстать на экране размером с телефона не удобно  разрешением fhd. И с диагональю 75 сидя перед ним с разрешением 4k. Значит для Вас существует оптимальный размер в этих пределах так называемый локальный экстремум. Удобство это чисто индивидуально и задавать вопрос об удобстве того или иного у общественности не совсем верно.

Answer (score -2):

За ноутбуком в любом случае работать менее удобнее чем за настольным компьютером.

Разрешение лучше брать больше - 2560х1600+. Разрешение больше стандартного нужно чтобы помимо сайта на экране помещались еще и DevTools.

А количество дюймов... ну я не знаю, ноутбук должен быть мобильным, 15-дюймов - это же наверняка 2кг! Он неподъёмный.

Берите новый [Macbook Air](https://www.apple.com/ru/macbook-air/) с процессором M1. Дешево ($999) и сердито!